# Burp Suit attack every 10 minutes

Tags: burp

I am in the intruder tab of Burp Suit Free Edition v1.7.03 
I'm able to make an attack which is generally a HTTP request but what I want is HTTP request should be made every 10 minutes instead of default 3 seconds time interval (approx)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where the 3 seconds default came from, I think Burp tries as fast as possible by default. But anyways, I think you can set it with the **Throttle** settings under **Intruder/Options/Request Engine**. You need to set the **Number of Threads** to 1, and set **Throttle** to 600000, like this:

[Setting throttle to 10 minutes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyFoF.png)